# Python matplotlib - Large Window on Linux

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, window

Simple Question, how do I set matplotlib to display a fullscreen window? Here is the code for doing it on Windows...

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.state('zoomed')
```

Which works fantastic... on Windows.

I'm using Linux, and it does not work there, only allowing the following window.state() modes: "normal", "iconic", and "withdrawn". None of which are a full screen window.

Thanks in advance!

Update: Thank you [BHawk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4434679/bhawk) for you recommendation of using `mng.frame.Maximize(True)`, but that throws the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/conrad/PycharmProjects/Mike/Third/Habit Tracker/habittracker.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/conrad/PycharmProjects/Mike/Third/Habit Tracker/habittracker.py", line 77, in main
    mng.frame.Maximize(True)
AttributeError: 'FigureManagerTkAgg' object has no attribute 'frame'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
mng.window.showMaximized(True)
```

Comment: This does not work, I've updated my original question with an error message etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works unter Linux (Ubuntu 19.10):

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.resize(*mng.window.maxsize())
```

If you want your matplotlib content to go fullscreen without any window borders and buttons, try

```
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()
```